# Error on make installing DCMTK on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, dcmtk

In first place, sorry about my bad english, i'm not a american. Anyway, i'm trying to install the DCMTK on Ubuntu and when i do the make all step it keeps giving me that error:

[Error output from make all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGSkp.png)

And [here](http://pastebin.com/b0a26rFj) the entire output from make all

I'm using this answer to install and also reading the install steps that came with DCMTK zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to build the - almost 6 years old - DCMTK 3.6.0 source code with a recent version of gcc? This does not work. I would recommend to use the latest DCMTK snapshot, which can be downloaded from here: http://dcmtk.org/download/dcmtk/snapshot/

If you'd prefer to fix the issues you've experienced, here is one of the patches that you need to apply to DCMTK 3.6.0: http://git.dcmtk.org/?p=dcmtk.git;a=commit;h=dbadc0d8f3760f65504406c8b2cb8633f868a258

Answer (score 1):

Don't see why the make failed, it says one of the functions is out of scope which may mean the zip file or the contents that where extracted may be corrupt.

Download the source again, try the latest snapshot first and follow the INSTALL, get it from their official site at [dcmtk.org](http://support.dcmtk.org/redmine/projects/dcmtk/files)

If you're just looking to use some of the utilities like dcmodify or dcm2xml they can be installed with apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get install dcmtk
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to test the dcmtk install is working? Does anyone know where to find those instructions or how to test the install is working?